# remove glitch when switchpanel visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a little problem regarding the appearance in Visual Basic, when I click the single 2x2 button the display changes and is normal, but there is a little unsightly glitch when I spam the click on the single2x2 button.

the following is the code that I made

```
    Sub switchPanel(ByVal panel As Form)
    Panel1.Controls.Clear()
    panel.TopLevel = False
    Panel1.Controls.Add(panel)
    panel.Show()
End Sub
Private Sub ordo2x2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ordo2x2.Click
    switchPanel(single2x2)
End Sub
```

This is a video example of the problem that I described above: https://pixeldrain.com/u/vevCf2b8

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to replace the Form with a UserControl. Then, if you have already created this Control and shown it, why do you try to create it again, without checking if it already exists? In case you need to, for some reason, you have to **Dispose()** of the previous and replace it with the new one. Don't do this: `[Control].Controls.Clear()`, this doesn't dispose of anything, it just removes all Controls references from the collection, but the Controls are still all *alive*.

Comment: I don't understand, can you give me an example? what should I add or remove in the code?

Comment: Could you provide some related code about 'single2x2' form? It will help others make a test.